# Log4j maven module in desktop/android application

Tags: android, maven, log4j

I have a complex project where the core `maven` module (which has dependency on `log4j`) is inherited by other

2 maven modules

- the first one is a desktop swing application
- the second one is an android app.

I want to build the first module (swing app) as is so it will inherit the standard `log4j` implementation (from parent core module), but for the second module I would like to use Android implementation of `log4j`. How to tell maven to do such thing ?

Comment: Just specify two different dependencies in different modules.

Answer (score 2):

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions

In the android app where you declare your dependency, something like:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But then make sure you also include the Android replacement for Log4J.